Do clutch master and slave cylinders need to be changed together?
When one is failing can you just change the primary part or is doing both generally recommended

Just change the one that's failing. There isn't much overlap in those jobs. The only thing that you'd need to repeat in case you're changing the other one later is bleeding the system, which is not a big deal.
